# hardware-selection needs to die

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [hardware-selection](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hardware-selection) is littered with shopping questions and nothing else. It should die a painful death. A very, very painful death.

Comment: ***LIVE SUPPORT!! YOU SHUTTUP!!!***

Comment: I've closed all the shopping questions in the tag.. It can be Baleeeeted by the devs.

Comment: @Devs It'd be super nice if Mods could merge a tag into $NULL and remove the tag from all it's currently tagged questions. Seems to work already up until a sanity-check in the SQL or something.

Comment: This is not a question. I don't understand why hardware selection questions are bad.

Comment: @Flimm it's a request to have a dev delete the tag. The tag is bad because its clearly about shopping or product recommendations which are off-topic

Comment: There are 53 questions with this tag, 43 have been closed. It's a good indication of less than topical questions. If someone wants to go through them and save the good ones (removing the tag as you go) and flag the rest for deletion I'll happily oblige.

Comment: Look - if the tag itself said lemmings would you jump off a cliff?

Comment: No, but I'd also want to blacklist that one as well. It's just plain **not** a good tag. What situation could you possibly use that tag in that is on topic? Also, tags should be nouns that categorize the question.

Comment: Apologies, this is probably the wrong place to say that I like shopping questions...

Comment: Yep, considering that they're off-topic across the **entire** stack exchange network - not just Server Fault. If you have a subjective issue like what to buy, you can always pop into [chat] and discuss.

Comment: @RichSnow: This isn't [the right room for an argument](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQFKtI6gn9Y). May I request that you familiarise yourself with the [faq] and our [/about](http://serverfault.com/about) page. Cheers.

Comment: @MDMarra Thanks, great suggestion!

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Answer (score -11):

Great to see as always, more and more users who are seeking input from others being told their questions are worthless and go away.

Do you actually feel you're helping ANYONE with stupid rules like these? I think it's more likely you're just enjoying lording over other users.

Comment: Children, please behave. For what it's worth Chris, downvotes on meta sites do not indicate "wrong", they indicate "I disagree". That's why there's no individual rep on this part of the site. You're totally entitled to your opinion, and its just as valid as anyone elses opinion on here, and this is the correct place to voice it.

Comment: Also, I see that this answer has collected some "delete" votes. This is a totally inappropriate use of the delete feature. You can't just go around deleting opinions you don't like.